# ag-grid : how to apply pipe on the data after setting the data manually?

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid along with angular 8.

on getting the data from backend, I am able to apply pipe successfully.

this pipe(testFilter) append the empty rows in the grid.

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
            [rowData]="rows | testFilter" [columnDefs]="columns" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
```

this grid is editable in nature, so a user can change the data.

now I have a button on which I am setting the default value of grid i.e the data which came from backend.

however it is setting the default value, but not applying the pipe on that.

```
this.gridApi.setRowData(this.defaultRows);
```

can we apply the pipe manually ?

Comment: just update the `rows` variable instead of using `this.gridApi.setRowData`. Then the pipe will be applied.

Comment: Do you update rows with the value of this.gridApi.setRowData(this.defaultRows)?

Comment: Yes, it is also updating but not able to see empty rows

Comment: @Viqas already tried, not working

Comment: could you post your pipe `testFilter` please.